# MongoDB for a user tagging system

Tags: mongodb

The requirement for this system is to store information about users and report on it.  So...it makes sense for a User to be an individual document, and perhaps have an "event" or "tag" array on that user and a query could be performed that returned all users that had a specific event...that's fine.  But - I'm worried about performance here.  After a while this data is going to get very big, very quickly.

Let's say we have a really active user - it has billions of events and that particular user document is approaching gigabytes in size.  In this instance, would the simple act of pulling that document down is going to take a while...and updating then sending it back will take a while as well (although I guess individual properties could be updated individually...)

What are the ways of managing this?

Comment: "What tool to use" questions are off-topic and your question already got 3 of 5 close-votes, so I edited it to make it on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

A document approaching gigabytes in size is already technically impossible, because MongoDB puts a limit of 16MB on documents.

When you have documents which grow over time, it is usually better to put the growing data in a separate collection as individual documents. The reason is that when a document grows beyond its initial size, MongoDB needs to move the document to another file location from time to time, which greatly slows down updates.